# How to sort python dictionary based on similar values and keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

In my case, i have a random values of dictionary like this :

```
dict = {2: 1, 27: 28, 56: 28, 57: 29, 58: 29, 59: 29, 28: 29, 29: 1, 30: 1, 31: 1}
```

if i illustrate that dictionary into hierarchy chart, it will be like this :
[image]

my goal are to sorting that dictionary sequenced by its values than following by similar keys in parallel into a list. for example, if we start from keys = 27, so the result will be like this :

```
list = [ 27, 28, 29, 1 ]
```

is there any idea to solve this problem or whether python has a capabilities library to solve it ?

Comment: Quick note: don't use `dict` and `list` as variable names in Python because you'll overwrite the built in functions with the same names.

Comment: ok, i agree with your suggestion, i've been add a chart so it will be easier to understand my goal

Comment: Can you please explain your logic more clearly? I'm completely lost as to what you're trying to do. If you're starting from 27, how does 1 end up in there?

Comment: that graph means that 27 has values = 28, so does next where 28 has value = 29, and 29 has values =  1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you looking seems to be the path to the root where each key in the dictionary maps to its parent. Using a generator function the problem can be solved easily:

```
d = {2: 1, 27: 28, 56: 28, 57: 29, 58: 29, 59: 29, 28: 29, 29: 1, 30: 1, 31: 1}

def path_to_root(d, start):
    yield start
    while start in d:
        start = d[start]
        yield start

print list(path_to_root(d, 27))
```

Result:

```
[27, 28, 29, 1]
```